# SQL server T-SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table its name - UserData and its contain one column name -
   UserInfo.

UserInfo column contains following values likes

demo.acc.in

swiss.com.au

austa.edu.co

I want to extract the following information from it...

```
Output

 demo
 swiss
 austa
```

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 5):

You can use `left()` and `charindex()`:

```
select left(userinfo, charindex('.', userinfo + '.') - 1)
```

Note that the `+ '.'` means that this will work even when `userinfo` does not contain a space.